# Camel REST DSL swagger output contains invalid responseSchema element

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, apache-camel, swagger

I am developing a REST API using spring-boot (2.0.5) and camel (2.22.1).  The API is defined and auto-documented using Camel's excellent REST DSL.  All working great, apart from when I examine the generated swagger (JSON or YAML) my responses contain an invalid property `responseSchema` which appears to be a duplicate of the valid `schema` property which I'd expect.  This causes validation errors when rendering via the swagger-ui.

Here is a sample of my API definition:

```
rest("/things")
.get("/").outType(Thing[].class)
.param().name("param1").type(RestParamType.query).required(FALSE)
  .description("param 1").endParam()

.responseMessage().code(200).message("Some things..")
  .header("number-of-things").dataType("integer").endHeader()
  .endResponseMessage()

.responseMessage().code(400)
  .message("Bad request.")
  .responseModel(Error.class).endResponseMessage()
```

Which produces the following output in the `responses` section of my swagger:

```
400:
  description: "Bad request."
  schema:
    $ref: "#/definitions/Error"
  responseSchema:
    $ref: "#/definitions/Error"
```

It looks like I'm hitting this [issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/issues/772) and there are a couple of suggestions for resolving this but I'm not sure which is preferable in a SpringBoot app, and besides I haven't got either solution to work yet.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, and after investigation I found that it is camel bug, so created issue, you can see description https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13340. It will be fixed from camel 2.23.2